# What am I doing wrong with this equation with functions: $f(n+2)=f(n)f(n+1)$?

Tags: functions

I'm trying to solve the following equation:

> Let $ f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} $ be a function, where $f(n+2)=f(n)f(n+1), \ \forall n \ge 0$, $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1)=-1$. What is $f(7)$?

I tried to check $f(1)$, where $f(1) = f(1)f(1+1) \implies f(1)=f(1)f(2) \implies f(1)=2$.

I'm definitely doing something wrong, or I don't understand that subject right. Anyone who can explain to me how to solve, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Not sure how you got $f(1) = f(1)f(1+1)$?

Comment: I don't understand your calculation.  If we take $n=0$ we get $f(2)=f(0)f(1)=1\times (-1)=-1$. Is that what you were trying to do? What was the question?

Comment: @lulu How did you get to that -1 in multiplication?

Comment: Which stage don't you understand?  I took $n=0$ in the given functional equation.  That gives us $f(0+2)=f(0)\times f(0+1)$ which is the same as $f(2)=f(0)\times f(1)$.  Then I just substituted the given values for $f(0)$ and $f(1)$.

Comment: Should't it be $f(\color{red}{1}+2)=f(\color{red}{1})f(\color{red}{1}+1)$?

Comment: You didn't actually indicate what the original question was.  Assuming the question was "determine $f(n)$", Hint:  use the functional equation to write down the first $10$ or $20$ values of $f(n)$.  That should make it obvious what the function is.

Comment: @lulu I'm trying to get $f(7)$

Comment: Ok.   Now that you have $f(2)$, use it to get $f(3)$.  Then use that to get $f(4)$ and so on.  This should be a very rapid operation.

Comment: There's no reason to think $f(1) = f(1)f(1+1)$.  Rather $f(3) = f(1)f(1+1)$.  You should have $f(1)  = f(-1 + 2) = f(-1)f(-1+1)=f(-1)f(0)$.... that is if you want to go they way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well playing around.

$f(0) = 1; f(1) =-1$ and

$f(2) = f(0+2) = f(0)f(0+1) = f(0)f(1) = 1*(-1) = -1$.

$f(3) = f(1+2) = f(1)f(1+1) = f(1)f(2) = -1*(-1) = 1$ and ... well, can you continue.

.... if we know $f(k)$ for all $k$ up to $n$ then we can figure out that $f(n+1) =f(n-1 + 2) = f(n-1)f(n)$.  And therefore given enough time we can solve all $f(n)$.

We can probably even figure out $f(n)$ based on certain properties of $n$ so we can maybe figure out $f(7)$ and $f(2020)$ without having to go all the way.  But we can just figure out $f(7)$ but going four more times.

=====

Alternatively:

$f(7) = f(5+2) = f(5)f(6)$.  Dang it!  We need to know $f(5)$ and $f(6)$.

$f(6) = f(4+2) = f(4)f(5)$ and $f(5) = f(3+2) = f(3)f(4)$ so

$f(7) = f(5)f(6) = f(3)f(4)f(4)f(5) = f(3)f^2(4)f(3)f(4)=f^2(3)f^3(4)$.  Dang it! We need to know $f(3)$ and $f(4)$.

$f(4) = f(2+2) = ........$

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function:

[image]

I personally find it simpler to define:

$f(n) = f(n-1)f(n-2)$.